# To generate new fields automatically in a list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, list, workflow, development

I have list with some fields in that, and in one field I can enter a value then a number of new fields must be populated. The number of new fields created must be equal to the value specified 
Columns to be iterated in the list based on the value specified
1.Department section 
2.Name of employee
 3.employee Designation
 4.shift time Drop down with values(morning, noon, night)
 5.Remarks if any

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example workflow to create a text field in a list:

[image]

If the workflow initiator user does not have required permissions, use the "App Step" construction.

---

In my opinion, you can also use Content Types with these fields and set the appropriate Content Type when necessary.

Comment: how to proceed ,with the content types?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using InfoPath, you can create a data connection to an XML file, and use that to set the valid values based off the original field.

For example, assuming I'm understanding you right, I could set up a field called "State," and then, based off the State, populate the "Cities" field with the appropriate values.

If this is the approach that you would like to use, let me know and I'll provide more in-depth details.

Comment: Actually the requirement is that when the user enter 3 in one of the field then we have to populate the above set of columns 3 times.

Comment: You could probably do that in InfoPath... Just make a conditional formatting rule for each column that says something like "If value < 1 then hide" for the first column, "if value <2 then hide" for the second column, etc.

Comment: actually using InfoPath is not allowed in the system.Could you please help me to proceed with your first answer ??

Comment: Sorry-I'm only familiar with InfoPath for customizing forms.